Is it possible to track a certain item and store the information automatically in a blockchain?
I'd like to develop a tool, in which you scan with a smartphone a QR-Code of a product, which contains information like what kind of product is this and the tool sends the information and information such as  the date, time, location and from whom it was scanned to blockchain or smart contract where it gets stored and benefit from the blockchain technology such as immutable and backtracking of data. So you can see it as a product tracking which the information is stored in a blockchain.
Is this possible? and how hard would the development be? What do I have to develop or what are the steps?
Im really new to blockchain and smart contract and what I have recently got to know is that blockchains cannot use external data and must use an oracle...
but chainlink or oracles do not offer that kind of information but rather general information such as weather and stock prices and not individual information of small events.
Is there a method in which I can send an Information of a QR-Code automatically to a blockchain automatically after the code was scanned?
Are Smart Contracts involved in this application or are just blockchains use of storage or what role would the smart contract do?
I hope somebody understands my question and forgive my ignorance and stupidity.
Best Regards,
Drake

While this is a good question, StackOverflow is not a medium for open-ended question like this, but only for exact programming question. I suggest you ask this question on some learning-focused forum like /r/EthDev on Reddit.

It is possible to do, and smart contract is not needed. Moreover, one my fried already developed such thing.
What is challenge of this project:
If you will upload into blockchain info about each item, this will:

Be expensive, because of you will need to pay TX fee or gas for each item.
Quickly inflates blockchain, and it will contains info about all items, and that will be millions of them.

Solution, I think, to develop special service, which does following:

Keep all info about items locally (name it as "item file").
Build local Merkle tree of that item files.
Upload into blockchain root of the Merkle tree.
When user's app requests server, it provides serial ID.
Server found item file, and provide to client:
Item file as is
Merkle path to that Merkle root in the tree.
Block hash or height, where this MErkle Root is uploaded.
Client take this proof, and assured - item file is correct.
Interesting question - how to proof uniquness of item file. Because of, malicious issuer, can crease several item files, and return reference and proof to one of them, which he wish to show right now.
To make a proof unique, need to use chain of transactions, when some change is reused to same address.

Or if using Emercoin blockchain, you can use NVS to keep proof of unique record.
If you need assistance, contact me in telegram @olegarch
